# Matching pandas substring with dict key and replacing with dict value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, match

Assume I have `df` and `d` below. I want to, for each row in `col`, check if there is a match with an item key in `d`, and if so replace the value in `col` with the corresponding item value, otherwise drop that row. (There can't be more than one match).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['sdffzdhellojkh', 'fegky', 'ouewfzdworldqf']})

d = {'fzdhello': 'hello', 'fzdworld': 'world'}
```

The output in this case would look like:

```
df
    col
0   hello
1   world
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try extract and map:

```
df['col'].str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(d.keys())))[0].map(d).dropna()
```

Output:

```
0    hello
2    world
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

series.str.extract then map:

```
df['col'].str.extract('('+ '|'.join(d.keys()) + ')',expand=False).map(d).dropna()
```

---

```
0    hello
2    world
Name: col, dtype: object
```